# Is there a way of retrieving records with ListViews AND with a certain communityId?

Tags: apex, api, jsforce

I'm currently getting records from listviews through the JsForce "listview" method and whenever i want to get records from a certain community i get them with the "find" method which i can pass the proper communityId as a parameter. My question is, is there a way to merge this two? if so, that would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance.